# How to change a file in-place with data from stdin in bash/awk/sed

Tags: bash

I want to build a simple command or function in bash that would take a file (e.g. .bashrc)

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ls="ls -hNFCs --color=auto -I NTUSER.DAT\* -I ntuser.dat\*"
alias mv="mv -i"
alias cp="cp -i"
alias rm="rm -i"
alias df="df -h"
alias du="du -h"
alias curl="curl -s"
alias c1="awk '{ print \$1 }'"
alias c2="awk '{ print \$2 }'"
alias c3="awk '{ print \$3 }'"
alias c4="awk '{ print \$4 }'"
alias dcp="docker container prune -f"
alias sup="scoop update \*"
###
alias docker='docker -C /trajano/docker'
```

then with a function I want to do something like

```
pullbashrc() {
  COMMONRC=$(curl -s https://gist.github.com/trajano/myrc)
  CUSTOMRC=$(??all contents from ### and including ###)
  echo $COMMONRC $CUSTOMRC > ~/.bashrc
}
```

So it will combine my bashrc from gist but add the local customizations via `CUSTOMRC`

I think I figured out how to do the CUSTOMRC

```
tail -n +$(grep -n "###" ~/.bashrc | cut -d ':' -f1) ~/.bashrc
```

Seems to do what I want.  I think I just have to combine this with a few things and I will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with.  Kind of wish I can get rid of the temp file

```
pullbashrc() {
  curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trajano/71553de32f335092ad62f2f301cadd0f/raw/7006ef1c1bf10520e47089b385b8f9670d5ce96e/.bashrc > /tmp/bashrc
  tail -n +$(egrep -n "^###" ~/.bashrc | cut -d ':' -f1) ~/.bashrc >> /tmp/bashrc
  mv -f /tmp/bashrc ~/.bashrc
}
```

Comment: You don't need complicated calculations to get line numbers to feed to `tail`. Instead of the second line, try `sed -n '/^###/,$p' ~/bashrc >> /tmp/bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting your personal bashrc contents out to a separate file, then sourcing it in.

One-time setup:

```
sed -n '/^###/,$p' ~/.bashrc > ~/.bashrc.personal
```

Alias definition:

```
alias pullbashrc='{ curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trajano/71553de32f335092ad62f2f301cadd0f/raw/7006ef1c1bf10520e47089b385b8f9670d5ce96e/.bashrc; [ -r ~/.bashrc.personal ] && printf '\n%s\n' "source ~/.bashrc.personal"; } > ~/.bashrc'
```

I included a leading newline as the existing file didn't seem to contain a trailing newline, and the extra line would be harmless otherwise. There's a test inside the compound statement that looks to see if you have a readable `~/.bashrc.personal` file before requesting its inclusion in the output.

If I was going to do something like this, I'd go the direction of a function, as you did, and add some error-checking (perhaps network connectivity is down), so that I didn't clobber an existing `~/.bashrc` file with truncated contents.